# Argument of type “const [structname] *” is incompatible with parameter of type “const [structname] *”

Tags: c++, function, pointers, structure

I am trying to include a structure in a library function in C++.

The structure goes like this:

```
struct NET_IN_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB{
DWORD                             dwSize;
EM_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB_TYPE    emOperateType;
FACERECOGNITION_PERSON_INFO       stPersonInfo;
char                              *pBuffer;
int                               nBufferLen;
};                                                `
```

And the function in which it is included goes like this:

```
BOOL CLIENT_OperateFaceRecognitionDB(
 LLONG                             lLoginID,
 const NET_IN_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB      *pstInParam,
 NET_OUT_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB      *pstOutParam,
 int                                 nWaitTime = 1000,
 );
```

I'm defining the structure to a pointer by writing the following lines:

```
const struct NET_OUT_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB{
    DWORD                             dwSize = sizeof(NET_IN_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB);
    EM_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB_TYPE    emOperateType = NET_FACERECONGNITIONDB_ADD;
    FACERECOGNITION_PERSON_INFO       FACERECOGNITION_PERSON_INFO1;
    char                              *pBuffer = '\0';
    int                               nBufferLen = 10;
} *pstInParam;
```

but when I call that structure into the function using this line:

```
CLIENT_OperateFaceRecognitionDB(m_LoginID, pstInParam, pstOutParam, 1000);
```

I am getting an error saying

**Argument of type “const NET_IN_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB *” is incompatible with parameter of type “const NET_IN_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB *”**

This is very unusual, because both the argument and the parameter are of the same type. What mistake have I done?

Comment: Wtf is "structure to a pointer"?

Comment: Your definition for `pstInParam` looks very odd.  It's a pointer but you're trying to assign the members of the `NET_OUT_OPERATE_FACERECONGNITIONDB` being pointed to without actually reserving any memory for that structure.

Answer (score 1):

> This is very unusual, because both the argument and the parameter are of the same type.

They are not of the same type (which the error message tells you, though it is not very helpful in doing so).

What's going on here is that your declaration of `pstInParam` is in fact defining an anonymous `struct`, and then introducing a variable that is a pointer to this anonymous `struct`.

This is more readily seen in a reduced example, which [yields a more helpful error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JIfA2j1aCBTEhRxI) on recent GCC versions:

```
struct some_struct {
  int member;
};

bool some_function(const some_struct*) {
 return false;   
}

int main()
{
  const struct some_struct {
    int member = 0;
  } *param;

  some_function(param);
}
```

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:15:22: error: cannot convert 'const main()::some_struct*' to 'const some_struct*' for argument '1' to 'bool some_function(const some_struct*)'
   some_function(param)
```

---

What you (probably, depending on the ownership semantics of `CLIENT_OperateFaceRecognitionDB`) want to do is either to declare a `some_struct` and pass its address to the function:

```
int main()
{
  const some_struct param{0};
  some_function(&param);
}
```

...or to allocate it on the free store:

```
int main()
{
  const some_struct* param = new some_struct{0};
  some_function(param);
  delete param;
}
```

In the latter case, please consider using smart pointers if possible.